# How to troubleshoot Apache httpd that just went silent?

Tags: httpd, apache-2.2

I had one of our Apache httpd servers "die" in a weird way overnight. I have looked at all relevant logs and cannot find anything out of the ordinary.

This happened in our development environment thankfully, but I am rather concerned because our dev environment nearly identically mirrors our production environment.

*Can anyone tell me what could have happened here?*

### Symptoms & Troubleshooting Steps

- Apache httpd was completely unresponsive
- Load average of 0.0 across the board
- No log anomalies
- `ps aux | grep httpd` appeared normal
- `iptables -L` showed port 80 open
- SELinux is enabled and properly configured: no AVCs logged
- No configuration changes were made to any system components, no matter how insignificant
- Apache httpd was *reloaded* at `17:11:25` server time to clear APC (php) cache

  - Successful requests were made after this reload through `17:20` after which I left for the day
  - Nothing remarkable happened after reload
- The following morning the httpd processes were unresponsive
- Telnet to port 80 connected successfully

  - Manual GET, POST, OPTIONS, and HEAD requests received no response whatsoever; nothing logged

### Logs

#### access_log

```
172.22.44.41 - - [03/Mar/2011:17:20:18 -0600] "GET /admin.php?type=notifications HTTP/1.0" 200 44326 "http://umc.dev.example.com/admin.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.597.107 Safari/534.13"
172.22.44.41 - - [04/Mar/2011:14:45:16 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 62921 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.597.107 Safari/534.13"
```

#### error_log

```
[Thu Mar 03 17:11:25 2011] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Thu Mar 03 17:11:25 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Mar 03 17:11:25 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Mar 03 17:11:25 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 04 14:45:05 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 04 14:45:05 2011] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context user_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Fri Mar 04 14:45:05 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Mar 04 14:45:05 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Mar 04 14:45:05 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Mar 04 14:45:05 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

#### ps aux | grep httpd

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      8477  0.0  1.9 408748  9876 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:03 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   19933  0.4 14.6 436436 74692 ?        S    Mar03   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   19936  0.4  8.4 419708 43148 ?        S    Mar03   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

#### /var/log/messages

```
Feb 27 04:02:01 webdev1 syslogd 1.4.1: restart.
Mar  4 14:43:35 webdev1 yum: Installed: strace-4.5.18-5.el5_5.5.x86_64
```

### Versions

#### OS & Kernel

- CentOS release 5.5 (Final)
- Linux webdev1.int.example.com 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 5 17:52:25 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#### Apache httpd

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Aug 30 2010 12:28:40
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:3
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Compiled using: APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

#### PHP

- php53u-5.3.5-3.ius.el5

#### Repositories used

CentOS Base & Updates for all packages with the following exception: php53u from [IUS Community](http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/repoview/) repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from disk full happening, there's not much to go there. If it doesn't happen again then it will fall on the *weirdness* category. Do you have the `dmesg` output to see if there was something wrong with the OS (oom killer, for example).

If it happens again, then you will must use `strace` following forks to see what exactly is blocking the processes.